# How can I make the mainMenuStrip look glossy in a Windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to make a nice looking UI with Windows Forms but the main problem I have is that the MenuStrip in Windows Forms looks flat. In WPF everything is shiny and pops out, how can I make it so that it looks like that? I tried using a gradient background image but the buttons stayed as blue rectangles. I am also willing to use an alternative control. Any ideas?

I forgot to mention, regarding alternative controls I am looking for something free and open-source.

Comment: go for telerik controls http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/controls.aspx

Comment: That says WPF, I'm trying to make my program in Windows Forms. Or Am I reading it wrong?

Comment: go telerik.com and searh for windows forms control in the complete site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal suggestion would be that you move from menustrips to "*Office-like*" menus / ribbons.

Please go through the following links / search through these sites
 for more custom controls for winforms

**Code Project**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12204/Flat-style-menu-bar-and-popup-menu-control-for-Win

*Windows Ribbon for WinForms (Part 1-21)*

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62412/Windows-Ribbon-for-WinForms-Part-1-Introduction

**Code Plex**

http://ribbon.codeplex.com

http://fluent.codeplex.com

http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com

Comment: My porgram is relatively simple, I don't think I could use a ribbon, but I will look into the FlatMenu